# Convert SQLite Blob to Hex to string

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm writing a console app that will grab some data from a Chrome extension and email me a report. The data is stored as JSON in the localstorage file, which is a sqlite database. If I copy the hex and convert it online at http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx it converts to the JSON properly. But, no matter how I try to do it in C#, it looks like this:

[image]

Here's my main portion of code:

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        var dbLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbLocation"];
        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;", dbLocation)))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var response = connection.Query<string>("SELECT hex(value) FROM ItemTable WHERE key = 'state'").Single();
            var json = ConvertHex(response);
            //var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChromeData>(json);
        }
    }
```

For the ConvertHex function here's everything I have tried, all of which have the same result. These are pulled from various other StackOverflow answers.

```
    public static string ConvertHex(String hexString)
    {
        try
        {
            string ascii = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
            {
                String hs = string.Empty;

                hs = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
                uint decval = System.Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16);
                char character = System.Convert.ToChar(decval);
                ascii += character;

            }

            return ascii;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

        return string.Empty;
    }

    private static string HexString2Ascii(string hexString)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i <= hexString.Length - 2; i += 2)
        {
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(Int32.Parse(hexString.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber))));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static byte[] FromHex(string hex)
    {
        hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
        byte[] raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
        {
            raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
        }
        return raw;
    }

    static string HexStringToString(string hexString)
    {
        if (hexString == null || (hexString.Length & 1) == 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
        {
            var hexChar = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
            sb.Append((char)Convert.ToByte(hexChar, 16));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

Change the `try` block of `ConvertHex` as said below.

Look into comments for the details.

```
public static string ConvertHex(String hexString)
{
    try
    {
        //DECLARE A VARIABLE TO RETURN
        string ascii = string.Empty;

        //SPLIT THE HEX STRING BASED ON SPACE (ONE SPACE BETWEEN TWO NUMBERS)
        string[] hexSplit = hexString.Split(' ');

        //LOOP THROUGH THE EACH HEX SPLIT
        foreach (String hex in hexSplit)
        {
            // CONVERT THE NUMBER TO BASE 16
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);

            // GET THE RESPECTIVE CHARACTER
            string stringValue = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(value);
            char charValue = (char)value;

            //APPEND THE STRING
            ascii += charValue;
        }

        //RETURN THE STRING
        return ascii;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: This throws an error "Value was either too large or too small for a UInt32." The split doesn't have anything to split, so the hex is an entire JSON object, that's pretty long.

Comment: Is it possible for you to put your sample hexString here?

Comment: I posted it here, since it's so long: https://gist.github.com/tgeorge91/e848244bf1f16d97ec4ad92a33cf6a46

Comment: Found the problem.... This is your output :{"username":"batmanswagstore","version":5,"config":{"tasks":[{"ena

Comment: In your hex string the spaces are replaced by "zero,zero".. I mean hex characters "7B 22 75" are represented as "7B00220075".

Comment: So you have to alter your logic little bit to cnsider zeros. for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
                {
                    String hs = string.Empty;
                    hs = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
                    if (hs.CompareTo("00") != 0)
                    {
                        int value = Convert.ToInt32(hs, 16);
                        string stringValue = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(value);
                        char charValue = (char)value;
                        ascii += charValue;
                    }
                }

Comment: SImple way of fixing is, ensure the spaces are not replaced with "00" and use the code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a way to ensure the spaces aren't replaced with 00, since that's not my code/application at all. I tried to update my code with the snippet from your comment and couldn't get it to work. Could you possibly update your answer to show the full function that I'd need?

Comment: Never mind, :D. I was calling the wrong function. That's what happens when you have too many similarly named functions trying to do the same thing. It worked! Thank you!!!!